# Error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly; UNAUTHORIZED: authentication;

Tags: java, docker, skaffold, kaniko

I am trying to deploy application on K8s using skaffold, kaniko and desktop-docker.
Getting below error msg

error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "index.docker.io/chandramgc/autodockerdeployer:6d5351a-dirty": UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:chandramgc/autodockerdeployer Type:repository] map[Action:push Class: Name:chandramgc/autodockerdeployer Type:repository]]
pod has failed

Looking of any guidance in resolving the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Skaffold.yml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1
kind: Config
build:
  tagPolicy:
    gitCommit: {}
  artifacts:
    - image: chandramgc/autodockerdeployer
      # jib: {}
      kaniko:
        image: mgit/base:kaniko-executor-debug-stable
        buildContext:
          localDir: {}
        cache: {}
  cluster:
    dockerConfig: 
      secretName: dockercred
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s-*
```

Dockerfile

```
# For Java 8, try this
# FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# For Java 11, try this
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre

# Refer to Gradle build -> finalName
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/autodockerdeployer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# cd /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

# cp target/spring-boot-web.jar /opt/app/app.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

# java -jar /opt/app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

dockercred

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry dockercred --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v2/ --docker-username=<username> --docker-password=<password> --docker-email=<email>
```

k8.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: auto-docker-deployer-app
  name: auto-docker-deployer-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auto-docker-deployer-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auto-docker-deployer-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: autodockerdeployer
          name: auto-docker-deployer-app
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: auto-docker-deployer-app
  name: auto-docker-deployer-app
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8095
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8095
  selector:
    app: auto-docker-deployer-app
  type: NodePort
```